# ActionScript 3.0 code to calculating the input text then multiply by the price of the product

Tags: actionscript-3

I have five input boxes and one dynamic I have 3 different prices for four of the input box. The input boxes is where the user will put the number of pounds of coffee that they want to buy ranging from 1-9. 1 and 2 pounds cost 12 dollars, 3 and 4 pounds cost $ 11.50, and 5 to 9 pounds of coffee cost $ 10. The fifth input box is one price of $ 5 for 1-9 pounds of coffee.  If I/user wants to buy 2 pounds of one brand and 1 pound of another brand then the price should be $ 11.50per pound. Here is the code that I have:

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;  
    // Event listener for the Calculate button 


calc_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculate); 


    //Function to calculate total coffee price  
        function calculate(event:MouseEvent):void   {       
    //Define the price cost variable for dynamic text box   
        var price:Number;   
        var totalCost:Number;   
        var numberOfPounds:Number;      
    //Populate the total cost minus tax dynamic text field      
        if (numberOfBmg.text == "1" || numberOfBmg.text == "2")     
    {       
        price  = 12     
    }   
        if (numberOfSm.text == "1" ||  numberOfSm.text == "2")  
    {       
        price = 12  
    }   
        if (numberOfC.text == "1" || numberOfC.text == "2")     
    {       
        price = 12  
    }   
        if (numberOfK.text == "1" || numberOfK.text == "2")     
    {       
        price = 12;     
    }       
        if (numberOfBmg.text == "3" || numberOfBmg.text == "4")     
    {       
        price = 11.50   
    }   
        if (numberOfSm.text == "3" || numberOfSm.text == "4")   
    {       
        price = 11.50   
    }   
        if (numberOfC.text == "3" || numberOfC.text == "4")     
    {       
        price = 11.50   
    }   
        if (numberOfK.text == "3" || numberOfK.text == "4")     
    {       
        price = 11.50;  
    }       
        if (numberOfBmg.text == "5" || numberOfBmg.text == "6" || numberOfBmg.text == "7" ||            numberOfBmg.text == "8" || numberOfBmg.text == "9")     
    {       
        price = 10  
    }   
        if (numberOfSm.text == "5" || numberOfSm.text == "6" || numberOfSm.text == "7" ||       numberOfSm.text == "8" || numberOfSm.text == "9")   
    {       
        price = 10  
    }   
        if (numberOfC.text == "5" || numberOfC.text == "6" || numberOfC.text == "7" ||          numberOfC.text == "8" || numberOfC.text == "9")     
    {       
        price = 10  
    }   
        if (numberOfK.text == "5" || numberOfK.text == "6" || numberOfK.text == "7" ||  
numberOfK.text == "8" || numberOfK.text == "9")     
    {       
        price = 10;     
    }       
        if (numberOfGc.text == "1" || numberOfGc.text > "1")    
    {       
        price = 5;  
    }       

        numberOfPounds = int(numberOfBmg.text) +int(numberOfSm.text) +int(numberOfC.text) +int(numberOfK.text) +int(numberOfGc.text);   
        totalCost = numberOfPounds*price;   
        total.text = String(totalCost);
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Thank you Chris
```

For your time and all of your guidance
Without your help I would still be at this
Trying to find the solution
My deepest appreciate could never show my graditude
*/

// Event listener for the Calculate button
calc_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculate);
function calculate(event:MouseEvent):void
{

```
//Variable that will hold the total price
var totalCost:Number;
totalCost = 0;
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//Populate cost for Gc_ti coffee
if (Number(Gc_ti.text)>0)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(Gc_ti.text) * 5;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//Populate cost for Bmg_ti.text coffee

if (Number(Bmg_ti.text)<3)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(Bmg_ti.text) * 12;
}
else if (Number(Bmg_ti.text)>4)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(Bmg_ti.text) * 10;
}
else
{
    totalCost +=  Number(Bmg_ti.text) * 11.5;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//Populate cost for Sm_ti coffee
if (Number(Sm_ti.text)<3)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(Sm_ti.text) * 12;
}
else if (Number(Sm_ti.text)>4)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(Sm_ti.text) * 10;
}
else
{
    totalCost +=  Number(Sm_ti.text) * 11.5;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//Populate cost for C_ti coffee
if (Number(C_ti.text)<3)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(C_ti.text) * 12;
}
else if (Number(C_ti.text)>4)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(C_ti.text) * 10;
}
else
{
    totalCost +=  Number(C_ti.text) * 11.5;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//Populate cost for K_ti coffee
if (Number(K_ti.text)<3)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(K_ti.text) * 12;
}
else if (Number(K_ti.text)>4)
{
    totalCost +=  Number(K_ti.text) * 10;
}
else
{
    totalCost +=  Number(K_ti.text) * 11.5;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------



total_td.text = String(totalCost);
```

}

// I hope this helps someone because I couldn't find the answer to my question above on the internet
thanks Stack Exchange for being here and helping newbies to have a better understanding of programming languages.

Sincerely,
Danny